# Extracting ListItems from a List in a SharePoint Site

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to extract a list of items in a SharePoint Site below the root site at `host.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite`. I've tried a bunch of different methods, but only one seems to work:

```
var host        = "host.sharepoint.com:/";
var siteName    = "mysite";
var listName    = "MyList";

// Generate the Client Connection
var graphHelper = new ApplicationAuthenticatedClient(ClientId, Tenant, ClientSecret);
await graphHelper.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

// Code: itemNotFound
//Message: The provided path does not exist, or does not represent a site
//var list = await graphHelper.GraphClient.Sites[$"{host}{siteName}"].Request().GetAsync();

// Returns a Site, no Lists.
//var list = await graphHelper.GraphClient.Sites[host].Sites[siteName].Request().GetAsync();

//Code: itemNotFound
//Message: The provided path does not exist, or does not represent a site
//var list = await graphHelper.GraphClient.Sites[host].Sites[siteName].Lists[listName].Request().GetAsync();

// List retrieved, but no Items
//var site = await graphHelper.GraphClient.Sites[host].Sites[siteName].Request().Expand("lists").GetAsync();
//var list = await graphHelper.GraphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists[listName].Request().Expand("Items").GetAsync();

//Code: invalidRequest
//Message: Can only provide expand and select for expand options
//var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>() { new QueryOption("expand", "fields") };

// This works
var site = await graphHelper.GraphClient.Sites[host].Sites[siteName].Request().GetAsync();
var list = await graphHelper.GraphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists[listName].Items.Request().Expand("Fields").GetAsync();
```

I've finally managed to get it to connect, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to navigate to the list, rather than the two API calls? (Assuming that I don't know the Site ID beforehand)

Edit: Using the Graph Explorer, I can access the items using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{host}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{siteName}:/lists/{listName}/items?expand=fields`, but I don't know how to  (or if) access that API call in a single call in the .NET API.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I was on the right track with `var list = await graphHelper.GraphClient.Sites[$"{host}{siteName}"].Request().GetAsync();` but the URI was not formatted correctly.

The correct Site ID for https://host.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/MyList is:

```
Sites[host.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:"]
```

Retrieving the list from the code in my original question would look like this:

```
var host        = "host.sharepoint.com";
var siteName    = "mysite";
var listName    = "MyList";

// Generate the Client Connection
var graphHelper = new ApplicationAuthenticatedClient(ClientId, Tenant, ClientSecret);
await graphHelper.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

var list = await graphHelper.GraphClient.Sites[$"{host}:/sites/{siteName}:"].Lists[listName].Request().GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible in one API call.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{host}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{siteName}:/lists/{listTitle}/items?$expand=Fields
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I did find that API call using the Graph Exlporer before I asked the question, but neglected to mention it in the original question. I've since updated the question. My original question still stands - how can I access this list with a single API call in the .NET SDK?